# How do I achieve a navigation bar like the one used in iBooks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

The navigation bar in iBooks is exactly what I'm looking to implement. That is, a transparent top bar with the return button in the top left and some buttons in the top right to invoke actions.

However, I'm not exactly sure how this effect would be accomplished. The transparency especially. Can anyone point me in the right direction of how I might accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom UIView subclass. Just add some buttons and set the alpha of the view. Use the controller's UINavigationController to push or pop controllers.The navigationbar should be hidden.

Comment: short: don't use a navigation bar at all

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a navigationControllerBar, I would use a simple UIToolbar to do this. Especially you can have only two button on the navigationControllerBar (left and right button) unlike on a UIToolbar.

The UIToolbar is absolutely customizable, you can set the opacity to 0% and the opaque to NO, after it can be transparent....

Answer (score 0):

With UIView or UIToolbar the alpha is fully customisable. You should subclass one of those two (UIView or UIToolbar), add your buttons and then go from there.